# Get Columns Width

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I am using PHPExcel library for reading Excel file. I want to get each column width.

I am trying the following code.

```
$objWorksheet->getColumnDimension('A')->getWidth();
$objWorksheet->getColumnDimension('B')->getWidth();
```

It always returns -1 not exact width of Column.. If I use following codes before.

```
$objWorksheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
$objWorksheet->calculateColumnWidths();
```

It returns auto size width not exact width from Excel file.

Can anyone help me? Here is screenshot of my excel file.

[image]

Comment: Is this for a file that you've loaded? If so, what type of file is it?

Comment: A value of `-1` means use MS Excel's default column width

Comment: I want to get actual width from Excel file.

Comment: MS Excel doesn't always store the actual width in a file..... when it stores a `-1` it means use the default

Comment: The default column width (-1) is 8.43 characters wide; that is not an exact width. For more information: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214123

Comment: You can't get my question.

Comment: @ShakeelAhmed - explain your question in more detail, including showing what you expect to see and what you actually see.... we've tried to answer as best we can based on the vague question

Comment: @MarkBaker... I've attached screenshot of Excel file in my Question. See column Username is more wider than ID.. but both returns -1... I want to get exact width of column ID, Username and so on.

Comment: If this is an Excel file that you're loading into PHPExcel, are you setting `readDataOnly` to true?

Comment: No, I am not using readDataOnly... How can I set this?

Comment: OK..... go back to my original question.... what format file is this? If it's an xls or xlsx file, and has fixed column widths, and you haven't used readDataOnly(true), then a call to `$objWorksheet->getColumnDimension('A')->getWidth();` should return the actual width, not -1

Comment: This is Excel 2007 file. and generated using PHPExcel library. My aim is get widths of each column and store it in DB. Next time when Execl file will generate then I want to set columns widths from previous file. I tried the following line $objPHPExcel->setReadDataOnly(true); but getting error of undefined function.

Comment: You're generating it using PHPExcel? Then are you setting the column widths yourself when you generate the file? If so, then you should know what you're setting them to; if not, then they'll default to -1.... unless you're using autosize.... and then it only calculates the width to use when you execute the save, or explicitly call `$objWorksheet->calculateColumnWidths();`

Comment: I am not setting widths yet. Yes but I will set them in future.

Comment: and I checked codes. I am already using ... $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

Comment: So if you're calling `$objWorksheet->calculateColumnWidths();` and then calling `$objWorksheet->getColumnDimension('A')->getWidth();`, it shouldn't be returning -1, but the actual width that it has calculated

Comment: If you're reading the file and `$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);` then you're telling PHPExcel __not__ to read any information like column widths

Comment: You are right @MarkBaker. ... I removed line $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true); and now I am getting actual widths of columns.. Thank you again... Please post this line as answer so I can mark it as solved your answer.